# Use md5sum to verify file in a script

Tags: shell-script, hashsum

I want to verify a file using `md5sum -c file.md5`. I can do that by hand, but I don't know how to check the validity in a script.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use `md5sum`'s return status:

```
if md5sum -c file.md5; then
    # The MD5 sum matched
else
    # The MD5 sum didn't match
fi
```

To make things cleaner, you can add `--status` to tell `md5sum` (perhaps GNU's version only) to be silent:

```
if md5sum --status -c file.md5; then
    # The MD5 sum matched
else
    # The MD5 sum didn't match
fi
```

Shorter forms work just as well if appropriate:

```
md5sum --status -c file.md5 && echo OK
```

Comment: `md5sum --status -c file.md5 && echo OK` doesn't check for missing or extra files unfortunately

Comment: @Erik what version of `md5sum` do you have? Regarding missing files, on the systems I’ve checked, `md5sum --status -c file.md5 && echo OK` does fail (and doesn’t print “OK”) if a file listed in `file.md5` is missing. Regarding extra files, `md5sum -c` never complains about extra files, it only checks the files listed in the given checksum file.

Comment: `md5sum --status -c file.md5 && echo OK` yields
`md5sum: stat 'foo': No such file or directory` and `OK` on a mac

Comment: You can put hashes in the script directly with something like `echo 098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6 test.txt | md5sum -c --status`