# How to verify checksums if files to check are mounted on different location?

Tags: osx, hashsum

I use OS X and have several checksum files that are generated from different external harddisks.

If the checksum files are in the same location as the files to check then I can simply run eg.:

```
shasum -c sums.sha1
```

But in my case `sums.sha1` is located in `~/Desktop/sums.sha1` and the files to verify are in `/Volumes/fr-ubb-1` (external drive, read only).

I understand that it's not possible to pass a location parameter to `shasum`. 
What's the best practice to run the verification of my checksum file with files in a different location?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run it from the directory containing the files to check, and give it the full path to the checksum file:

```
cd /Volumes/fr-ubb-1
shasum -c ~/Desktop/sums.sha1
```

This works with most (perhaps all) checksum verification tools, not just `shasum`.

Comment: It does not, unfortunately, work with `md5` on macOS as it has no verification capability ([that I can see](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/md5.1.html)).

Comment: @Kusalananda isn’t there an `md5sum` on macOS? [At least some macOS users have it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/254875/86440) but I don’t know whether it came with the OS or was installed separately.

Comment: That's from GNU coreutils, which obviously can be installed on macOS, but isn't by default. `md5` is the BSD variation on the same theme. `md5` supports `-c` on other BSD systems (NetBSD and OpenBSD, but it means something else on FreeBSD).  My guess is that macOS is using an older version of it.

Comment: @Kusalananda OK, thanks for the clarification. I’m not familiar with modern BSD, but yes, macOS does tend to have old versions of the BSD tools...

Answer (score 0):

Or modify the content of the sums.md5 to include absolute path to files.